# Spring Boot and PreFlight requests

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-boot, cors

I am using `Spring Boot version 2.0.0.M5`

My `JavaScript` application is having issues calling my exposed Rest endpoints.
For security - I expect a header containing an api key to be passed in.
However - the preflight  request (Options) doesn't have the header set

The following `JavaScript` snippet reproduces the error for me

```
var baseEndpoint = "http://localhost:8480";
var data = null; 
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
xhr.withCredentials = true;
xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
  if (this.readyState === 4) {
    console.log(this.responseText);
  }
});
xhr.open("GET", baseEndpoint + "/api/issue/user/1");
xhr.setRequestHeader("x-api-key", "fdarwetr5467hyyerf");
xhr.setRequestHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept","application/json");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Origin", "localhost");
xhr.send(null);
```

Even if I get it to be an OPTIONS request - the `x-api-ke`y header is not passed

My cors setup in Spring Boot is as follows

```
@Override
public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry corsRegistry) {
    super.addCorsMappings(corsRegistry);
    corsRegistry.addMapping("/**").allowedMethods("*").allowedOrigins("*").exposedHeaders("x-api-key", "apiKey").allowedHeaders("x-api-key", "apiKey").allowCredentials(true);      
}
```

I was wondering what is the correct way to handle these preflight requests? Or has anyone got any recommendations for getting the header to be passed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this by adding a filter on all api requests
When the request method is OPTIONS - I just return out of the filter successfully

```
    if ("OPTIONS".equals(request.getMethod())) {
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        return super.preHandle(request, response, handler);
    }
```

Comment: Do you need to open all Options requests in your application?

Comment: I dont no..no specific need to do that

Comment: You do not need a custom filter for this. You can extend the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter configuration class and just override `void configure(WebSecurity web)` Inside just call `web.ignoring().antMathers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**");`